# What happens to one's invite, when that person leaves the organization

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

My question is:-
I have to send calendar invites for the whole year from my outlook calendar, but I am leaving this organization in one month.
So would the attendees still be able to see what I have sent as calendar invite after I leave the company??

Comment: If your leaving in a month, why don’t you let someone else send the invites, in case the event has to be modified after you leave?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the organisation will not change anything you've sent.

Invitations will stay in everybody's calendar. The issue is more removing them if needed. As the owner left the company, there'll be no way cancelling them, all participant will need to remove it from their own calendar.

Comment: Agree. The messages wouldn't be affected even if you leave the organzation (your mailbox is removed).

Comment: If you don't have other questions, would you mind marking the helpful post to an answer?